# Difference between rendering {{ var }} and {{ var|safe }} in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Say `var` is a variable passed with `return` from a view to a template. Could you please give me a simple example to understand the difference between rendering `{{ var }}` on the one hand and `{{ var|safe }}` on the other? I was not able to fully understand what is going on in the documentation: [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#safe), [2](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoEscaping). In which case `|safe` protects me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

The `safe` template filter allows html tags and entities in the content of `var`. Without it, your html will be escaped so you'll see things like

```
<div> &nbsp;
```

etc on your page.

Answer (score 3):

If **var** has html elements then the **safe** template filter will render it.

For example:

If var is **hi**

var|safe will be rendered **hi**
var will be displayed <b>hi</b>

Answer (score 1):

Simply saying django's `safe` method in template doesn't render any html tags in template